# Resolution of certain programs too small on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: display-resolution, installed-programs

I've installed two programs (teamviewer and filezilla) so far that the resolution is just too small. How can I fix this? Picture below shows what I'm talking about.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 13.

[image]

My issue is only happening on certain programs -> teamviewer and filezilla so far. Everything else is the correct size. The post that was linked looks to be for a system wide issue for all programs.

Comment: I've edited your question to embed the image :)

Comment: @AndroidDev the above post you linked to seems to be for a system wide issue on every program. My issue is only happening on certain ones such as FileZilla and TeamViewer. So far everything else works fine and is the proper size.

Comment: Well, even though TeamViewer has a "native" Linux package, it's actually just running the Windows version inside of a pre-configured WINE setup. Unfortunately, WINE DPI scaling is terrible, and even though there is a setting for it, many people find that only some elements of the application are scaled. So I'm not sure there's much you can do about TeamViewer. As for FileZilla, I'm not sure why it isn't obeying the system-wide DPI scaling setting...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, reducing the display resolution makes all items appear larger.
There is also the "Scale for menu and title bars" index that can be adjusted.
This option is located in "System settings/Displays" under the resolution bar. 
Hope that's useful, it works for me...